# android improve internal storage

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, sd-card, adoptable-storage

is it possible to use an sd card as part of a smartphone's internal storage, even rooting the phone?

I have read that google has been on that feature since android M, but what about versions like kitkat?

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Tell me your device name

Comment: for testing I am using a vodafone smart first 6. but the device belonging to the person who requested this from me is a selectline, some model I may not remember, but runs kitkat 4.4.2, and has 4gb of internal storage divided in partitions of 2 each, as I understood, and is using an sd card of 16gb.

Comment: the mobile device model is a selecline-854599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the layout of the device

You need to build a specific rom  and a specific recovery to adopt the sdcard

> **What do the *specific* rom  and *specific* recovery means ?**

Let me start by how android manages storage

As per kitakat the storage is determined by the `fstab` and the `storage-list.xml`

This define what blocks should be used for what purpose more specifically they determine the partition

> **To adopt the storage**

- You need to build a new rom  with modified `fstab` and
  `storage-list.xml`  *(till lollipop because android 6 uses only the

  fstab)*
- Then build twrp *(or any other recovery)* with modified `fstab` and
  `storage-list.xml`
- Then flash twrp and wipe everything using advanced wipe *a word of

  caution this will wipe your sdcard*

Enjoy

Comment: @pemq you can see HTC one x 's xda forum new layout that will give you more idea

Comment: @pemq do your phone has a external sdcard or a inbuild one?

Comment: external, but it has a built-in slot

Comment: @pemq you mean you have a sdcard ?

Comment: yes, that is it

Comment: I've cleaned up the old comments on this post. If you have a follow-up question, use the **Ask question** button to ask it where everyone can see and answer it. If you need to keep discussing things, join us in [chat].