# How to use an external sdcard as internal in Android Lolipop 5.1.1?

Tags: adb, external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I have seen option of making external sd card to internal in android 6 mobile phones but i have  android lolipop  5.1.1 how can i  make it adoptable or get that option is it feasable to get that option i found  some commands  but that command is not found in my /system/bin even after rooting to

```
sm has-adoptable 

sm set -force- adoptable true
```

> /sbin/sh: sm: not found

can i find some sm binary and use it ..i tried but my  phone got problem

Comment: You can't. That feature was only introduced with Android 6 and doesn't exist before that.

Comment: have you considered installing custom rom (if any)?

Comment: Duplicate of [android improve internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148249/android-improve-internal-storage)

Comment: @irfanlatif not its not duplicate bcoz i want to confirm that in andorid lolipop 5.1.1  is it possible to  use sm command and weather this adaptable feature is with  android 5.11

Comment: @alecx i am cureently trying alternative options like link2sd install location or swapping storage before  any  customized rom bcoz  i think its  risky to load custom rom  and dont know whether custom rom is available for my phone or not

Comment: @Androidquery if you make a quick web search you'll get hundreds of results discussing Adoptable storage was introduced in Android 6. Storage Manager (`sm`) is deeply integrated with other parts of Android code. It's not a standalone command, so can't be used independently. That's explained in the accepted answer to linked question.

Comment: @Irfanlatif it was not clearly said in any posts that it will not work  so i confirmed it with this post becoz once trying  sm command my  android  had been crashed i have to recover it from images so confirming before trying again ... thanx irfan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition MicroSD card to exFat and Ext 4 for link2sd?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210092)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sm is actually not a binary, it is a shell script for java program **which does not exist/work on 5.1-lollipop**

```
# Script to start "sm" on the device, which has a very rudimentary
# shell.
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/sm.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.sm.Sm "$@"
```

**to answer the headline**

a completely another solution for rooted devices only:

you can mount ext4 disk image (or ext4 partition) with same permissions like `/data`
(mount script example)

`/su/su.d/40sdextimg` start-up script with executable permissions

```
#!/system/bin/sh
until grep -qw /data/sdext2 /proc/mounts
  do
    mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime /storage/31D1-1308/data.sdext2.img /data/sdext2
    sleep 1
done &
```

then you can move apps and create symbolic links
(that's what Link2SD does)

```
mkdir /data/sdext2/com.textra-1
mv /data/app/com.textra-1/base.apk /data/sdext2/com.textra-1/
ln -s /data/sdext2/com.textra-1/base.apk /data/app/com.textra-1/base.apk
```

or bind mount whole folder
(assuming 2nd partition is mounted /data/sdext2)

```
mkdir /data/sdext2/media
chmod 0770 /data/sdext2/media
chown 1023.1023 /data/sdext2/media
chcon u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0 /data/sdext2/media
mv /data/media/. /data/sdext2/media
mount -o bind /data/sdext2/media /data/media
```

Comment: it's of course easier, moving whole folders is possible with same command. on per-app-selection is what Link2SD provides, for better performance and stability one should avoid moving critical apps to external sd as much as possible. i recommend moving apk only

Comment: @alecx will these scripts to start  sm to shell will work on android lolipop 5.1.1  as previously  i  pushed sm and sm.jar file downloaded from a site of different device and tried it   gave **java class error**  then **ABORTED**  error crashed the android and i had to recover through  system and other  images...will this  work and not damage the phone or os again.... as irfanlatif commented  that adoptable storgae has been introduced and work on only Android 6.0 and above

Comment: @IrfanLatif `An even simple approach is to mount SD card 2nd partition (or a loop file from first partition) directly to /data/app (or /data/data or /data/media). No extra steps required. But this should be.....` kindly modify the script and tell me detailed  steps to this  simple approach  script

Comment: @Androidquery just install Link2SD

Comment: @Androidquery as suggested by alecxs go with Link2SD. Setting up manually requires some advanced skills you may not feel comfortable with.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219678

Comment: 1. create some file on your MicroSD Card with `dd` + `mke2fs` (see [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210092)) 2. create mount script in *'/su/su.d'* (see above example *'40sdextimg'*) 3. create empty folder *'/data/sdext2'* (mount point for Link2SD) 4. reboot and check Link2SD storage info (invite me to some chat if you need more help)